# TFS work item field "Integrated in build" not populating

Tags: tfsbuild

TFS2012

We have CI builds on our 'Main' branch.  But when code is checked in and work items associated it is done on our 'DEV' branch.  Those 'DEV' changes are then merged to 'Main'.

I think this is pretty standard.  My question though is why do we not see "Integrated build" field on the work items updated after DEV is merged to Main?  Is there anyway to make this happen?

Comment: Association occurs on build, not merge. You also need to have a build triggered from the merge changeset.

Comment: I know the association is on build, but the first build doesn't occur until the code is merged to it's release branch.  I was hoping the association would be propagated to merge so that build would update the integrated build field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colleague found this blog article; [Custom Build Task: Include Merged Changesets (and Work Items) in Build Report](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/custom-build-task-include-merged-changesets-%28and-work-items%29-in-build-report).

Binaries [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=64a24e0938d6d062&id=64A24E0938D6D062!409&authkey=!AOAkUohlQ7MPbyQ).

It is apparently now part of the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/).